# best practice to sync two different systems users table

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am having a main stream website and I would like to include Forum functionality. Since it is a java based system, I opt for Jforum. Now since the JForum having it's own login table and use it from there, I would like to make this to use mainstream login sysem. Can any one post me what are the best practice to do it? Duplicating the data in both the table? Create a view and refresh periodically? I  am using MySQL database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying the data from one table to another is not a good idea, as it can introduce inconsistencies in the data.  The best solution is to create a [View](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_%28database%29), as you mentioned.  Simply add any columns that JForum needs to the main stream website database, and create a view that simulates the table name and column format that JForum is expecting.  If done correctly, JForum should simply read from the VIEW which is nothing but a SQL query that changes your existing Users table to appear the way it's expecting it to.